# Table CAN'T be zoomed using javascript (Ruby on rails related)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

Basically, I am applying zoom to my table(id:nav) using Javascript today like it is normally done.

It is supposed to zoom according to the width of the main div, which is set to the width of the window.

But strangely, result is always 0! Does this happen to anyone else?

I have tried two ways without success. Why can't a table be zoomed programmatically?

Following is my two approaches:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#nav").css("zoom", $("#main").width()/1920);
});
```

and:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#nav").css({
        zoom: $("#main").width()/1920
    });
});
```

My css styling over this specific element:

```
#nav {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

and my html section:

```
<table id="nav">
<tr>
<td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td>
<td>d</td>
<td>e</td>
<td>f</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

table gets the zoom, but the value of zoom is 0, which is obviously wrong. Thanks for the help!

Comment: It "works" for me, but obviously the results are nonsensical: http://jsfiddle.net/2BqR7/ What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Answer (score 0):

It should work, but if not, try putting the table inside some **div** and then zoom that div.

Another though - you are using #main element's width - could it has really 0px? or probably it doesn't exists?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the help first of all.
This is surely a first-timer-level question in website development.

**UNLESS**, look closely here, if you are developing using **RUBY ON RAILS** and has **Turbolink** enabled, which should be the default setting.

According to asset pipeline, all javascript files amongst others will be included in **any** web page.

The issue with me is that there were two js file implementing the "zoomer" while each of them uses different equations (meaning index.html uses ".page" to compute the zoom and the one in question uses "#main").

This causes this issue.

Solution is simple, avoid name collision when developing in Ruby on Rails. Period.